# Wikipedia: Processing from dumps, how to filter out hidden categories?

Tags: wikipedia

I am processing Wikipedia from these dumps [http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20141208/ ].

Information about which categories are associated with specific pages is available from 
[http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20141208/enwiki-20141208-categorylinks.sql.gz ], and meta data about categories themselves are available from [http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20141208/enwiki-20141208-category.sql.gz ].

But I am not able to segregate hidden categories from visible ones.
For example, page [Anarchism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchism) has following categories as visible:

```
Anarchism
Political culture
Political ideologies
Social theories
Anti-fascism
Anti-capitalism
Far-left politics
```

While the dump also suggests many other junk labels like:

```
Articles_containing_Ancient_Greek-language_text
Articles_containing_Spanish-language_text
Articles_prone_to_spam_from_November_2014
Articles_with_DMOZ_links
Articles_with_French-language_external_links
Articles_with_inconsistent_citation_formats
CS1_French-language_sources_(fr)
CS1_German-language_sources_(de)
Good_articles
Use_British_English_from_January_2014
Wikipedia_indefinitely_move-protected_pages
```

along with the earlier ones.  Now Wikipedia calls them as "Administration Categories" or "Hidden Categories", but such things are not tagged in dumps.

Since I have filter out those labels, my options are either to filter them out by pattern matching, or get the visible labels directly from the pages (which is problematic because the Categories are written differently in category dumps and pages).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All hidden categories (or, more specifically, their pages) are directly in the (hidden) category [Category:Hidden categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Hidden_categories).

So, what you need to do is to get the page id for each of the category pages and then find whether that page is in Hidden categories. To find the page id based on name, you may want to use the `page.sql` dump.

For example, the page id of the page "Category:Articles containing Ancient Greek-language text" is 39721267 and `categorylinks.sql` indeed does contain the entry:

```
(39721267,'Hidden_categories','ANCIENT GREEK\nARTICLES CONTAINING ANCIENT GREEK-LANGUAGE TEXT','2013-06-25 09:42:34','Ancient Greek','uppercase','subcat')
```